# Use try_emplace in unordered_map for user defined types

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map

I'm experimenting with `try_emplace()` for an `unordered_map`. I created two user-defined types that I try to construct in the `try_emplace()` method, but I cannot get it to compile. The following code returns an error:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1674:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘bar::bar(int, int, int)’
 1674 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
      |
```

I tried using `map.try_emplace("hi", 1, {1, 3});`, and `map.try_emplace("hi", 1, foo{1, 3});` but it did not work. How do I correctly use this method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct bar {
    int c; 
    foo f;
};

int main()
{
    foo f {1, 2};
    bar b {3,{1,2}};
    
    unordered_map<string, bar> map;
    map.try_emplace("hi", 1, 1, 3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you add a `bar(int, const foo &)` constructor to `bar` then `map.try_emplace("hi", 1, foo{1, 3});` will work. If you add `bar(int, int, int)` then `map.try_emplace("hi", 1, 1, 3);` will work

Comment: You are right. I wonder why `bar b {3,{1,2}};` doesn't need a ctor then? But try_emplace needs it?

Comment: Actually I think my question should be reversed. Why does try_emplace need an explicit custom ctor, when the `bar b {3,{1,2}};` works just fine without it.

Comment: @rookie `bar b {3,{1,2}};` uses [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) when no constructors are present, whereas `try_emplace()` does not use aggregate initialization at all, it constructs a `std::pair`  using its `std::piecewise_construct_t` constructor and a couple of `std::tuple`s to forward inputs to the constructors of the `std::pair`'s two elements (ie the map's key and value).

Comment: From documentation, try_emplace forwards the args `std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...` . I guess I'm not fully clear how that makes a difference. Is there a better way? But happy to accept that explanation as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, `std::piecewise_constructor` needs it, I think it makes sense now. The example from documentation helped 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct